# Python Selenium - send_keys not sending any information to element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying out Selenium for the first time so I apologize if there is an obvious mistake or problem with my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('search')
searchBox.send_keys('Programming')

searchButton = driver.find_element_by_id('search-icon-legacy')
searchButton.click()
```

So I tried this and it loads the page fine but, it does not input any characters into the searchBox (I quadruple checked that the id was correct - copied it directly from the inspector).

**NOTE:**
My internet is really REALLY slow and it takes YouTube approx. 20 seconds to fully load, so I thought that was an issue so I tried;

```
...
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('search')
...
```

But this did not work either.

I did use XPATH instead of finding it by element ID at the start and that did not work.

I checked and copied the XPATHs and IDs directly from the inspector and nothing so far has inputted anything into the textbox.

What could be the problem? (1)

and does the webdriver wait for the page to load/find the element before doing anything after it being initialized with the driver.get('websiteAddress')? (2)

**NOTE:** I double checked that I was selecting the right element as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send keys to the  input tag with id = search. We use webdriver waits to allow the element to be usable after driver.get so the page loads correctly.

```
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search']"))).send_keys("Programming")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: No problem accept the answer. upvote the answer and have a nice day.

Comment: I did both, the upvote won't show due to my low reputation level. Quick question, would it be bad practice WebDriverWait constantly throughout my code?

Comment: You can use wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 30) then just do wait.until. Webdriverwait makes your code more stable. Normally it's used right after driver.get.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the waiting time:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

delay = 40
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@role='form']//input[@id='username']")))
```

Then it just waits on the element, for as log as delay is, but will continue as soon as the element is found, that the best way to wait on slow connections.

Comment: Hi, this did not solve my issue but thank you for the information! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Whoops, python never throw any errors (I am too used to c++ compiler lol) after the delay so I thought it was working fine. I am going to try to solve the errors and will get back to you if anything changes :)

Comment: Hi, arundeep's comment helped, the "EC" was undefined. Thank you for helping I appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To relate elements more easily you can use ChroPath, it is an extension for google chrome / edge that allows you to see the path of an element, through cssSelector, Abs XPath, Rel XPath and the tag name, so when your code is not working you can try these other ways. Particularly this extension helps me a lot.